# clickhouse materialized view shows incomplete data

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I'm using materialized view to improve my queries performance over huge tables. And if the table is relatively small everything is fine. But for the really huge ones (about 1Tb and more) there's significant data loss.

I'm using a date for partitioning my tables. And in the materialized view I see that some dates are completely missing. On other dates data often are incomplete. Always near the lost dates intervals.

[look at the data distribution by dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYJFe.png)

I see such problems only for historical data from the table. All dates after view creation are absolutely correct and corresponds to the same data from the original table.

As from my experience such a behavior is close to the case when I cancel the query. In this case the view is created and some data are already inserted but not all of them. But I see no errors when I'm creating the views. Query finishes successfully.

Is there any ideas what can I do wrong?

my query for MV creation:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EXISTS huge_table.events_light
(
    server_date,
    -- other columns list
)
ENGINE = MergeTree 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(server_date) 
ORDER BY server_date 
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192  
POPULATE AS 
SELECT 
        server_date, 
    other columns list
FROM huge_table.events e 
WHERE event in (  events list )
```

I tried to change partition by from toYYYYMM(server_date) to server_date but it didn't help. And i tried to copy the original huge table to the smaller one by copying partitons to another table and creating materialized view over this shortened version of the same table. It worked. But as I understand just because this table is smaller.